# ECHO is not showing variables, even though they appear in SET - Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

In some code I'm working on, I need to connect to a terminal, which requires a terminal's IP address. Some of the code is here:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%A IN (%IPLIST%) DO (
NET USE //%%A /user:name password
SET TERMINAL=%%A
ECHO %TERMINAL%
)
```

However, after doing this, Echo responds with:

```
ECHO is off
```

As a test, I simply added SET after the ECHO %TERMINAL% Line, and according to it:

```
TERMINAL=10.123.45.6
```

So, my dilemma is that, according to SET, TERMINAL does indeed have a value, but ECHO doesn't agree.

The reason this is so important is because I cannot tell if the value is correct for future use in the rest of the code, where I implement it to enact different batches in a remote system.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I belive the reason is that `FOR` is evaluated as a single command and the environment variables are expanded before execution, so in your case it will be run like this:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1" %A IN (<%IPLIST% value>) DO (
NET USE //%A /user:name password
SET TERMINAL=%A
ECHO <%TERMINAL% value>
)
```

Since `%TERMINAL%` didn't exist before `FOR`, it'll be expanded to an empty string, hence the observed behaviour.

Try running the script with `@echo on`, it helps understand what's going on.

#### UPDATE

You might be able to get the behaviour you want with `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, see [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more details.